# Why does my static Docker give 502 errors?

Tags: docker, nginx

I am trying to create a docker deployable django site with a seperate static Nginx server. This used to work fine, but suddenly stopped working. I now keep getting 502 errors when trying to access the static folder. The Django app is running on a gunicorn server.

This is my nginx.conf

```
# nginx.default

upstream staticserver {
  ip_hash;
  server staticserver:9010;
  }

server {

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8010;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /static {
        proxy_pass http://staticserver;
    }

    listen 9000;
    server_name localhost;

}
```

My docker compose is this

```
version: '3'
services:
  staticserver:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./staticserver/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9010:80"

  djangoserver:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
      - staticserver
```

If I go to 127.0.0.1:9000 I get the django site
If I go to 127.0.0.1:9010 I get the root of the static server
But, if I go to 127.0.0.1/static I get a 502 error.

The logs show entries like these

```
[error] 10#10: *25 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /static HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.21.0.2:9010/static", host: "127.0.0.1:9000"
```

This seems counterintuitive, as I'd expect it to be `http://172.21.0.2:9010/` with the static folder names stripped.

I've tried some of the other answers on relating topics, but so far, it seems it just stopped working. I suspect some issue in the config files that I am simply not aware of, but I can't seem to find my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to a port on the inner network solved the issue;

```
upstream staticserver {
  ip_hash;
  server staticserver;
  }
```

instead of

```
upstream staticserver {
  ip_hash;
  server staticserver:9010;
  }
```